# Intraclass correlation to validate a measure

Tags: likert, validation, intraclass-correlation

I would like to understand whether the output of an algorithm I developed agrees with the ratings of external observers. The number of observers is 10 and each of them rated on 2 3-point-Likert items 10 stimuli. The algorithm provides one measure (a real number) for each stimulus.

I am thinking about the use of intraclass correlation among observers and then to use this possible agreement (but I don't know if this sounds good and how to do this) to validate the output of the algorithm.

Thanks

Comment: Intraclass correlation is one measure of agreement and another popular measure is Kappa.  But although rater agreement could be partially credited to the algorithm, I think it is partially and perhaps primarily a matter of individual similarities and differences and you have no way to separate these effects unless you also use these same raters with a different algorithm for comparison.